# Definition without value does not fail

Tags: scheme

This tells Scheme that `x` means `3`:

```
(define x 3)  ; (define <id> <value>)
```

All good. But today I mistyped a definition:

```
(define y)  ; (define <id>)
```

To my surprise, there is no error! Later, I tried this supposedly errorneous definition on another Scheme implementation (MIT Scheme) to make sure I was seeing things right. On MIT Scheme, `(define y)` appears to be valid too.

Questions:

1. Is it valid to define something without a value? i.e. Is the `(define <id>)` special form mandated by any Scheme standards?
2. What is the use of defining something without providing a value?

Comment: 1. DrRacket disallows this, under `lang #r5rs`, as one datapoint. tio.run with Chez Scheme allows it. [the Report](https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) should provide some answers. 2. when implementing something like `letrec`.

Answer (score 0):

The form you describe is present in [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/final/r6rs.pdf). Here's what the report has to say about it:

"The second form of `define` is equivalent to

```
(define <variable> <unspecified>)
```

where `<unspecified>` is a side-effect-free expression returning an unspecified value."

Comment: Can you also provide a simple code example of its use?

Comment: I wasn't on the R6RS committee, you should ask Mike Sperber about that. My guess is that some language implementors wanted to be able to describe code that e.g. translates into C, where we allocate space for a value without specifying its value.